# Edit Lighting Web Component and retrieve code

Tags: lwc-wire-adapter, code, lightning-web-components, lwc-oss

My org recently had a lighting web component written launched into production. Unfortunately, the team we outsourced this to left off a necessary field. I would like to edit this code to include this field they left off. However, I know you cannot access it in the developer console, is there a way to pull this code from somewhere (we do not have a stored file of this code anywhere) and how should I reimplement a lighting web component.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve a web component directly from your org by using [SFDX](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli):

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m LightningComponentBundle:componentName -u orgAlias
```

Then you can use VS Code or another IDE to edit the code, and finally deploy it back:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-app -u orgAlias
```